# How many 5 digit numbers are greater than 63900 and do not have digits 8 or 9?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 5 digit numbers are greater than $63900$ which none of the digits should be 8 or 9 ?

#### Progress

Since the greatest number is $77,777$ and the smallest one is $64000$ so we've $13777$ between them, but we shouldn't count $[8,9]$ , $[80,99]$ , $[800,999]$, $[8000,9999]$. I don't know how to count how many times these numbers repeat in these $(13777+1)$ numbers.

Comment: What have you done so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Since the greatest number is 77,777 and the smallest one is 64000 so we've 13777 between them, but we shouldn't count {8,9} , [80,99] , [800,999] , [8000,9999] . I don't know how to count how many times these numbers repeat in these (13777+1) numbers

Comment: If you have not yet read `How To Solve It`, go get it and read it; it will serve you well in the future. Polya says that if there's a problem you cannot solve then there is a simpler problem that you can solve: find it and solve it.  Can you solve the simpler problem of how many numbers between 0 and 9999 have no 8 or 9?

Comment: Here's a hint: Suppose you had a bag containing a large number of identical brass house numbers. You go through the bag and throw out all the 8's and 9's. How many ways are there of choosing four digits from that bag?

Comment: It was my fault that I didn't write the appropriate description for this problem, my problem is not counting those numbers, since I reached the answer before which is (8^4+8^3*6*5). My problem was how to count how many times this unallowable numbers repeat in [64000, 77777] .

Comment: Well, again, break it down. Can you solve the problem of how many times they repeat in [70000, 80000] ?  What about [60000,70000] ?  What about [60000,64000]?  If you can solve those three easier problems then you can solve the harder problem.

Comment: Thank you Eric. Now I'm know that from the first step it wasn't clear for me what I'm gonna do by knowing how many times they repeat ! for example between [70000, 80000] we've 17 of them, which gives me nothing for do on it and finally subtract it from the total number. I didn't determine a convenient way to solve this problem. anyway, thanks for recommending "How to solve it" I'll read it for sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

How many starting with $7$? (how many digits can be used for one of the other places?)

How many starting with $6X$? where $X\in \{4,5,6,7\}$